# How to get a float from python to JavaScript without cgi

Tags: javascript, php, python, ajax, raspberry-pi2

I am running an apache server from a Raspberry Pi and have a python script that returns sensor input by printing it. This properly prints it to the console. Currently I have a php script that gets this output and shuts off a light if the sensor is reading is high, before printing it again. This also works when run from the console. The last part is javascript that is supposed to get the output from the php. It does that using ajax, which runs the "success" function, but gets "0" from the php script.

My php script:

```
<?php

exec ("python temp.py", $temp);
if((float)$temp[0]>28)
{
exec("gpio read 0",$state);
if($state[0]=="1")
{
include('gpio.php');
echo("Overheated: ".$temp[0]);
}
}
else
{
echo($temp[0]);
}
?>
```

My js:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "temp.php",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            alert("asd"+typeof msg);
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = msg;
            return msg;
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }

});
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try `var_dump()` to see the exact value and it's type. If it's not what you expecting, try adding `die()` or `exit()` at the end of script instead of closing bracket `?>`.

Comment: When I run the php from the command line, I get string(7) "26.9862", as expected. But the website prints string(0) "". Any clues as to why it's not displaying the proper value? And I currently have exit() in the php.

Comment: It seems that without casting, the php is getting a NULL value from the python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. It's probably user permission issues, because you get the output running script under your user from terminal. And browser, which is running it under server's user, returns an empty string.

Check `www-data` (or whatever) permissions when running script from your server. Set error reporting and run:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo exec('whoami');
```

If it prints out user who is not sudoer, set correct permissions to allow your `.py` script execution by that user.